# Olá, Tenho uma duvida sobre JSON e JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estou tentando criar um sistema de gestão de correspondência que gera a referência da mesma baseando no **último ID, e a Data atual**, estou usando HTML, PHP, JAVASCRIPT, utilizando o atributo **blur** do **javascript** *quando clico fora do campo remetente automaticamente o campo referência dever ser preenchido* a minha função tem funcionando normalmente quando executo ela em localhost com **HTTP** NÃO SEGURO
[image: funcionando com http não seguro]

No entanto quando executo ela em um servidor com certificado SSL (cpanel ou outros) isso é **HTTPS** ele não gera a referência automaticamente fornecida pela minha função
[image: com HTTPS não funciona]

Não sei se tem alguma coisa a ver com o meu JSON ou Javascript, **Abaixo está o código front do meu formulário**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("input[name='remetente']").blur(function(){
                          var $referencia1 = $("input[name='referencia1']");
                          var $referencia = $("input[name='referencia']");
                          $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                            remetente: $( this ).val() 
                          },function( json ){
                            $referencia1.val( json.referencia1 );
                            $referencia.val( json.referencia );
                            $referencia = ( json.referencia )
                            Swal.fire({
                              icon: 'info',
                              title: 'Sua Referência: '+$referencia,
                              text: 'ANOTE! não modifique o campo referência',
                            });
                          });
                        });
                      });
                      </script>
                    <form method="POST" action="ad_correspondencia.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Assunto</label>
                                    <input required type="text" required class="form-control" name="assunto" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Título da Correspondência">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Remetente</label>
                                    <input required type="text" required class="form-control" name="remetente" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Entidade que envia">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Referência</label>
                                    <input required type="text" class="form-control" disabled name="referencia" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nº de Referência">
                                    <input required type="hidden" class="form-control" name="referencia1" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nº de Referência">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**Este é o código da minha função (function.php) que ele deveria chamar**

```
<?php
include_once("../conexao/conexao.php");

function retorna($remetente, $connection){
    $data = date('dmy');

    $consulta_id = "SELECT * FROM correspondencias";
    $resultado_id = mysqli_query($connection, $consulta_id);
    while($ids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_id)) {
        $ultimo_id = $ids['ID'] + 1;
    };

        $valores['referencia'] = $ultimo_id.'ESP'.$data;
        $valores['referencia1'] = $ultimo_id.'ESP'.$data;

    return json_encode($valores);
}

if(isset($_GET['remetente'])){
    echo retorna($_GET['remetente'], $connection);
}
?>
```

o interessante é que mesmo em HTTPS quando executo diretamente esté código ele me apresenta os dados retornados em JSON

[image: fuction.php funcionando]

Portanto não sei exatamente onde está o erro, lembrando que estou começando na área da programação ainda sou iniciante!

Comment: já olhou se tem erros na ferramenta de desenvolvedor do brower? pode também usar o `.error` para pegar algum erro e ver qual o problema

Comment: Olha muito obrigado pela sua contribuição, parece que o elemente externo que estava chamando no caso o Jquery usei o http não seguro "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" logo ao mudar a url para https ele bloqueiou todas requisições externas não seguras neste caso em particular alterei as minhas requisições para https https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js